# Change data frames in iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple data frame that I want to do the same function over them. in order to avoid repetition, I would like to use itertion over them.

```
# read text files 
df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.txt", sep="\t", error_bad_lines=False, index_col =None)
df2 = pd.read_csv("df2.txt", sep="\t", error_bad_lines=False, index_col =None)
df3 = pd.read_csv("df3.txt", sep="\t", error_bad_lines=False, index_col =None)

df_all =df1[["personId","Time"]]

scenarios =[df2,df3]

for scenario in scenarios:
    df_all["Time"+???] = pd.merge(left=df_all, right=scenario[["personId","Time"]], on=["personId"], how="outer")

df_all.head()
```

How I can diffrenciate between the name of column "Time" that I can have all dataframe at the end (avoid overwrite them).

Comment: what are `df2,df3,df4`? are you tried here to append a dataframe to a string?  `"Time"+scenario`.

Comment: @snatchysquid, I have eddited. they are data frames

Comment: it is not clear what 'function' you need to 'do' for each dataframe. Regardless, perhaps you should append the dataframes (if they have similar columns and you have a way to segregate them downstream) for a start? `df_all = df1.append(df2).append(df3)`

Comment: As @snatchysquid said, how can you add DataFrame to string: "Time"+scenario